# Find the expression for function $g(x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was given that $g(0)=1, g'(0)=0$ and $g''(x)-g(x)=0$. Will I be able to get the exact expression for $g(x)$? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: What is your background in differential equations?

Comment: I havent taken any differential equation class, but this question happens to be the first part of a proof question of my analysis problem sheet.

Comment: This is nothing more that a useful observation that may or may not help you solve this using only 'elementary' methods. But what functions do you know such that $f''=f$?

Comment: The thing is that this is a very simple question to solve after an introductory course in ordinary differential equations. Before such a class, I don't understand why a professor would give you a problem like this. For a detailed description of equations like this, you can google second order linear ODE's (which this equation is)

Comment: It is rather easy to guess at least two solutions (try $g(x)=\mu e^{\lambda x}$ for suitable values of $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mu \in \mathbb{R}$). However it may be hard to check that you are thus finding *every* solution...

Comment: @Siminore Not that hard after you prove that the set of solutions for a vector space of dimension $2$, which is easy to do.

Comment: @Siminore The solution OP is looking for has $g'(0) = 0$ so it cannot be of the form $\mu e^{\lambda x}$, it has to be a combination of $2$ exponent functions...

Comment: Well, one should find a solution of the DE first. Then one can deal with the Cauchy Problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

For such a kind of equation where is a linear combination of higher derivatives a function, generally you expect an exponential function, or trigonometric functions (sine and cosine) to be solution.

So in that case it is assumed that $e^{mx}$ is a particular solution and substituted in place of g(x). So you get $$(m^2 - 1)e^{mx} = 0$$, so you get $(m^2 - 1) = 0$ which is called the auxiliary equation.

$m = -1 \mbox{ or } +1$ solves it as $m^2 - 1 = (m-1)(m+1) = 0$.

Now the general solution is a linear combination of these two functions, i.e.

$$ g(x) = c_1 e^x + c_2 e^{-x}$$, where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are arbitrary constants. If you now apply the initial conditions i.e $g(0) = 1$ and $g'(0) = 0$ you get two equations namely :

$$ c_1 + c_2 = 1$$ and $$c_1 - c_2 = 0$$, if you solve these real constants (hint add them and subtract these equations), then you get $$c_1 = c_2 =\frac{1}{2}$$. So the solution $$g(x) =  \frac{1}{2} e^x + \frac{1}{2} e^{-x}.$$

Verify that it satisfies every condition you have for $g$.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way of solving equations like this (equations of $g'' + a g' + b g = 0$) is to set $g(x) = e^{\lambda x}$ and try to find the appropriate $\lambda$. The equation you get is $$\lambda^2 + a\lambda + b = 0$$
which you can solve for $\lambda$. Then you have $3$ options:

1. If there exist $2$ distinct $\lambda_1\ne \lambda_2\in\mathbb R$ that solve the equation, then any solution to the original equation will take the form
   $$g(x) = Ae^{\lambda_1 x}+Be^{\lambda_2x}$$
2. If there exists one real $\lambda$ that solves the equation, then any solution to the original equation will take the form $$g(x) = (Ax+B)e^{\lambda x}$$
3. If the solutions to $\lambda^2 + a\lambda + b = 0$ are imaginary, then they are of the form $\lambda_{1,2} = a\pm bi$. In that case, any solution to the original equation will take the form $$g(x) = e^{a}\left(A\cos(bx) + B\sin(bx)\right)$$

In all three cases, you know that $g(x)$ is a function, depending on $2$ real numbers $A$ and $B$. Plugging in the known values of $g(0)$ and $g'(0)$ helps you determine what $A$ and $B$ are.